# Using Cron tabs to open localhost on a web browser

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to get my PI, which is running rasbian, to automatically run a bash command whenever the pi is booted. The ultimate goal is to open the `localhost` web page.

I ran

```
crontab -e
```

to open my crontab, and added this to the end of the file:

```
@reboot chromium-browser --kiosk localhost
```

but when I reboot the pi, nothing appears to happen. I then added this to test to see if crontab was even running or if I had formatting wrong:

```
@reboot cd && sudo touch sucess
```

But it executed exactly as expected

What am I missing?

EDIT 1: I did try doing this but it still didn't execute:

```
@reboot cd && chromium-browser --kiosk localhost
```

EDIT 2: I also saw an article suggesting that cron cannot find bash command locations, so I tried this as well, also to no avail:

```
@reboot cd && /bin/chromium-browser --kiosk localhost
```

EDIT 3: I also attempted to put the same command in root's crontab instead by doing `sudo crontab -e`But that didn't work either

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27572/how-to-auto-start-chromium-after-boot-on-the-raspberry-2-2015-01-31-debian-whee

Comment: Tried it, didn’t help

Comment: Does anybody have an answer?

Comment: Have you seen this post - https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8298 ?  They are adding the command to .bashrc  and it has further details on running the Pi in full kiosk mode (no title bars, menus, etc).